# Change the background color of cell in table layout for showing selected and unselected on cell (text click event)clickevent in android

Tags: android-activity

Help me to change background color on text click event on each cell when i click other cell previous selected cell should be unselect means only one cell which is clicked should change the background color.In my code how many cell i clicked,all clicked cell are changing background.I Want single cell should change the color at a time .
where allValues is array list and i am creating 5 column table.
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlparent);

```
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < allValues.size() / 5; j++) 
          {
                final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
                for (int y = 1; y <= 5; y++) 
                {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(allValues.get(k));
                    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
                     {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                      TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                      String text = tv.getText().toString();
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);       
                            }
                        });
                    tableRow.addView(tv);
                    k++;
                }
                tl.removeView(tableRow);
                tl.addView(TABROW);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of the question. first create the global text view with "null" value.where cell_shape is nothing just a border of text view.

Like  **public static TextView temp = null;** then replace the text view click listener  in **above code** only by the following.

```
                    ptv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                       {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                        if (temp != null) 
                         {
                        temp.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                     temp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                     temp = null;
                        }
                        if (temp == null) {
                        TextView ptv = (TextView) v;
                        String mdnStr =ptv.getText().toString().trim();
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        if (mdnStr.length()== 10) {
                        //do some thing whatever you want...
                                }
                            temp = ptv;
                            }

                        }
                    });
```